# Why can't I load my class by ExtClassLoader?

Tags: java, classloader

This is the structure of my Java project:

```
package: com.study.test
              ---- HelloWorld.java
              ---- Test.java
```

The content of **HelloWorld.java**:

```
package com.study.test;

public class HelloWorld {}
```

The content of **Test.java**:

```
package com.study.test;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.ext.dirs"));
        System.out.println(HelloWorld.class.getClassLoader());
    }

}
```

The value of the "**java.ext.dirs**" is:

```
D:\glassfish4\jdk7\jre\lib\ext;C:\windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext
```

I put the class file **HelloWorld.class** in directory:

```
D:\glassfish4\jdk7\jre\lib\ext\com\study\test
```

but the output of "`System.out.println(HelloWorld.class.getClassLoader());`" is:

```
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@70a0afab
```

Why the class HelloWorld isn't loaded by ExtClassLoader? ExtClassLoader is the parent class loader of AppClassLoader.

Comment: Here's a pretty good article on which classloaders do what: https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/understanding_java_class_loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension classloader load only classes from within Jar files.

assume following structure

```
src/Test.java
src/HelloWorld.java
```

amend `Test.java` as (**edit** this is not really necessary, only to show that the resolving is not done during compile time)

```
package com.study.test;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.ext.dirs"));
        System.out.println(Class.forName("com.study.test.HelloWorld")
            .getClassLoader());
    }
}
```

compile them

```
mkdir bin/
javac -d bin/ src/Test.java src/HelloWorld.java
```

create a Jar file containing the classes

```
jar cf test-hello.jar -C bin/ .
```

verify the content of the Jar file

```
jar tf test-hello.jar
```

output

```
META-INF/                       
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF            
com/                            
com/study/                      
com/study/test/                 
com/study/test/HelloWorld.class 
com/study/test/Test.class
```

move the `test-hello.jar` in the extension directory

```
mv test-hello.jar D:\glassfish4\jdk7\jre\lib\ext
```

run your class `Test`

```
java com.study.test.Test
```

output similar (the directories where copied from your questin)

```
D:\glassfish4\jdk7\jre\lib\ext;C:\windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext
sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@70dea4e
```